# Unexpected end of Stream Exception on redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception

I am testing an ASP.NET MVC application. There is a contoller with a method that looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginForm loginForm)
{
    // Do some work

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Admins));
}
```

The signature of Admins method looks like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Admins(ExtendedPagingForm form)
```

and I try to invoke it like this:

```
var url = $"{TestConfig.Instance.ServerUrl}/{actionMethod}";
var sendForm = GetFormContent(new MultipartFormDataContent(), sendData); //login and password

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, sendForm);
```

The response contains Internal server error with info:

> IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already
>   been read by another component.

[On MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) it is said that RedirectToAction returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action. So it must not work neither in browser, nor in Postman, but it works fine there. Can I force my httpClient to send POST request with data or some mock request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.
I changed `MultipartFormDataContent` to `FormUrlEncodedContent` and it works

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was already using `FormUrlEncodedContent` but it was still happening. Mine was a Xamarin project.

> Restarting Visual Studio and Emulator helped me.